# Single-ownership in computer science

Tags: database, definition, acid

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the correct place to ask this, but hopefully it is. I am trying to find the correct word in computer science to describe that "an object is **owned by a single entity**, and never by two or zero." Here is an example:

```
product    owner       is_valid
razor      gilette     true
bobsled    bob, jill   false
dirt       null        false
```

Is there a word to describe this property of single-ownership in computer science?

Comment: not a single word, a phrase perhaps... ***Mandatory relationship*** PK/FK relationship in a mandatory 1:M relationship.  A owner has zero to many products, a product is owned by 1 and only 1 owner.   I'd represent this as a ownerID in product table that isn't nullable. which makes it mandatory. a product couldn't be created w/o specifying the owner that way.

Comment: One-to-one relationship from the object to its owner?

Comment: @KevinHe exactly -- but is there a single word for that? Almost like "single-parented" ?

Comment: if you represent your objects as a directed graph, where a -> b represents b owns a. This is the same as saying every vertex has outdegree 1. The other property that might make sense for ownership is that your graph contain no cycles.